# How can i find a suitable distribution that fits my data?

Tags: r, distributions, generalized-additive-model, splines, distribution-identification

I have some data on prevalence of a given infection, provided for each country for 6 different age groups. I am trying to find a suitable distribution that may be suitable to model capture the prevalence data using `fitdistrplus` in R.

A histogram of the prevalence variable shows it appears somehow not unimodal, but a logit or log transformation suggests some skewness. Now, i am unable to find a suitable distribution that closely matches the data either because of wrong starting values or something i am unaware of. Could someone please advise through my line of code where i am missing the point?

Here's my data

```
prev=c( 0.4 ,0.4    ,0.3333 ,0.2273 ,0.2273 ,0.1818 ,0.0733 ,0.0807 ,0.2    ,0.2    ,0.2    ,0.1053 ,0.2083 ,0.1585 ,0.1017 ,0.1017 ,0.1017 ,0.1059 ,0.3902 ,0.3981 ,0.4103 ,0.4706 ,0.4706 ,0.4655 ,0.037  ,0.0432 ,0.0488 ,0.1538 ,0.1667 ,0.0556 ,0.1277 ,0.101  ,0.0641 ,0.034  ,0.0267 ,0.0463 ,0.0152 ,0.0277 ,0.0268 ,0.0211 ,0.0185 ,0.019  ,0.1818 ,0.2384 ,0.1442 ,0.1481 ,0.1111 ,0.1333 ,0.5018 ,0.2983 ,0.2649 ,0.2649 ,0.2649 ,0.2593 ,0.3442 ,0.2774 ,0.1269 ,0.1269 ,0.1269 ,0.1272 ,0.1708 ,0.136  ,0.048  ,0.048  ,0.048  ,0.0478 ,0.4261 ,0.303  ,0.1891 ,0.1891 ,0.1891 ,0.1891 ,0.12   ,0.0779 ,0.0306 ,0.0476 ,0.1    ,0.0862 ,0.1733 ,0.1386 ,0.0947 ,0.0822 ,0.0392 ,0  ,0.453  ,0.4287 ,0.3898 ,0.3756 ,0.3953 ,0.3776 ,0.3818 ,0.278  ,0.184  ,0.1529 ,0.1077 ,0.0769 ,0.2398 ,0.1421 ,0.1353 ,0.1269 ,0.1158 ,0.1228 ,0.1    ,0.1233 ,0.1162 ,0.1078 ,0.1238 ,0.0532 ,0.2636 ,0.1948 ,0.0767 ,0.0821 ,0.0661 ,0  ,0  ,0.0625 ,0.0635 ,0.0576 ,0.0455 ,0)
prev_log =c(,-0.916290731874155 ,-0.916290731874155 ,-1.09871229366844  ,-1.48148454812364  ,-1.48148454812364  ,-1.70484809723876  ,-2.61319467008953  ,-2.51701670370623  ,-1.6094379124341   ,-1.6094379124341   ,-1.6094379124341   ,-2.25094185984221  ,-1.56877593071521  ,-1.8420006856648   ,-2.28572797592762  ,-2.28572797592762  ,-2.28572797592762  ,-2.24526002637478  ,-0.941095850793126 ,-0.921052048975866 ,-0.890866679533997 ,-0.753746802688875 ,-0.753746802688875 ,-0.764643182265015 ,-3.29683736633791  ,-3.14191478373207  ,-3.02002496612304  ,-1.87210222191059  ,-1.79155948922539  ,-2.8895720777256   ,-2.05807151594364  ,-2.29263476214088  ,-2.74731091505551  ,-3.38139475436598  ,-3.62309171357593  ,-3.07261331788995  ,-4.18645985112991  ,-3.58632286578884  ,-3.61935339146533  ,-3.85848223850012  ,-3.98998454689786  ,-3.9633162998157   ,-1.70484809723876  ,-1.43380534379094  ,-1.93655405413129  ,-1.90986755770838  ,-2.19732458233655  ,-2.01515305179747  ,-0.689553645049815 ,-1.20965558746143  ,-1.32840288270411  ,-1.32840288270411  ,-1.32840288270411  ,-1.34976958643752  ,-1.0665323952047   ,-1.28229477110141  ,-2.0643559042618   ,-2.0643559042618   ,-2.0643559042618   ,-2.06199462807612  ,-1.76726199762767  ,-1.99510039324608  ,-3.03655426807425  ,-3.03655426807425  ,-3.03655426807425  ,-3.04072963948473  ,-0.853081218476271 ,-1.19402247347277  ,-1.66547930331773  ,-1.66547930331773  ,-1.66547930331773  ,-1.66547930331773  ,-2.12026353620009  ,-2.55232932610543  ,-3.4867552700238   ,-3.04492251774476  ,-2.30258509299405  ,-2.45108510131249  ,-1.75273108226058  ,-1.97616319222633  ,-2.3570412787901   ,-2.49859997692 ,-3.23907853218572  ,   ,-0.791863153499103 ,-0.846997905378206 ,-0.942121491908677 ,-0.979230531648029 ,-0.928110308679497 ,-0.973919844710791 ,-0.96285836769049  ,-1.2801341652915   ,-1.69281952137315  ,-1.87797116604712  ,-2.22840569481979  ,-2.56524940247054  ,-1.42795003638872  ,-1.95122424387908  ,-2.00026074380539  ,-2.0643559042618   ,-2.15589071384324  ,-2.0971982632691   ,-2.30258509299405  ,-2.09313486881184  ,-2.15244243456433  ,-2.22747762050724  ,-2.08908791873164  ,-2.93369688263454  ,-1.33332247635378  ,-1.6357818877737   ,-2.56785357060893  ,-2.49981726252375  ,-2.7165865321245   ,   ,   ,-2.77258872223978  ,-2.75671537308349  ,-2.85423271128029  ,-3.09004295302523  )

prev_logit= c(-0.405465108108164    ,-0.405465108108164 ,-0.693297184310321 ,-1.22362014408104  ,-1.22362014408104  ,-1.50419962375192  ,-2.53706927970004  ,-2.43287393559381  ,-1.38629436111989  ,-1.38629436111989  ,-1.38629436111989  ,-2.13967504741362  ,-1.33520318391046  ,-1.66943142031353  ,-2.17847678518065  ,-2.17847678518065  ,-2.17847678518065  ,-2.13332237313391  ,-0.446471606365144 ,-0.413388088547454 ,-0.362725333558318 ,-0.117735813499739 ,-0.117735813499739 ,-0.138219633747978 ,-3.2591354991539   ,-3.0977538879463   ,-2.96999403251747  ,-1.70510268121442  ,-1.60919793163141  ,-2.83236660395482  ,-1.92144963840068  ,-2.18616251763036  ,-2.68106426923659  ,-3.34680330959636  ,-3.59602879402624  ,-3.02520719549268  ,-4.17114314701801  ,-3.55823198562232  ,-3.59218772339256  ,-3.83715645178536  ,-3.97131128163224  ,-3.94413348039892  ,-1.50419962375192  ,-1.16147154828596  ,-1.78083547913187  ,-1.74958142777504  ,-2.07955404660204  ,-1.87209066895564  ,0.00720003110424186    ,-0.85540627073754  ,-1.02065414810202  ,-1.02065414810202  ,-1.02065414810202  ,-1.04960999247462  ,-0.644632980633109 ,-0.957395310832809 ,-1.92865072209642  ,-1.92865072209642  ,-1.92865072209642  ,-1.92594578361284  ,-1.57996809920715  ,-1.848917883068    ,-2.98736402388347  ,-2.98736402388347  ,-2.98736402388347  ,-2.99174945726301  ,-0.297781104608451 ,-0.833052605251155 ,-1.4558687662861   ,-1.4558687662861   ,-1.4558687662861   ,-1.4558687662861   ,-1.99243016469021  ,-2.47122772466839  ,-3.45567731445294  ,-2.99615235337533  ,-2.19722457733622  ,-2.36094155145952  ,-1.56241767553707  ,-1.82696688586421  ,-2.25755238028936  ,-2.4128241998986   ,-3.19908952396936  ,   ,-0.188556676938947 ,-0.287157092126485 ,-0.448152985209109 ,-0.508266441307169 ,-0.425087496976527 ,-0.499747538592836 ,-0.481915118406369 ,-0.954404025202189 ,-1.48947859735512  ,-1.71203463850249  ,-2.11445281474376  ,-2.48523169448451  ,-1.15377631396173  ,-1.79795650747586  ,-1.85488809078964  ,-1.92865072209642  ,-2.03281871625325  ,-1.96617800083069  ,-2.19722457733622  ,-1.96154444842424  ,-2.02891794827883  ,-2.11341266421927  ,-1.9569270151293   ,-2.87902948129223  ,-1.02734064673057  ,-1.4191173025572   ,-2.48805250040537  ,-2.41415043576666  ,-2.64820061925803  ,   ,   ,-2.70805020110221  ,-2.6911096159855   ,-2.79490724519548  ,-3.0434753172089   ,
group= c(1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6)
id= c(950   ,950    ,950    ,950    ,950    ,950    ,979    ,979    ,979    ,979    ,979    ,979    ,982    ,982    ,982    ,982    ,982    ,982    ,1008   ,1008   ,1008   ,1008   ,1008   ,1008   ,1151   ,1151   ,1151   ,1151   ,1151   ,1151   ,1166   ,1166   ,1166   ,1166   ,1166   ,1166   ,1199   ,1199   ,1199   ,1199   ,1199   ,1199   ,1244   ,1244   ,1244   ,1244   ,1244   ,1244   ,1267   ,1267   ,1267   ,1267   ,1267   ,1267   ,1277   ,1277   ,1277   ,1277   ,1277   ,1277   ,1286   ,1286   ,1286   ,1286   ,1286   ,1286   ,1292   ,1292   ,1292   ,1292   ,1292   ,1292   ,1306   ,1306   ,1306   ,1306   ,1306   ,1306   ,1323   ,1323   ,1323   ,1323   ,1323   ,1323   ,1367   ,1367   ,1367   ,1367   ,1367   ,1367   ,1399   ,1399   ,1399   ,1399   ,1399   ,1399   ,1438   ,1438   ,1438   ,1438   ,1438   ,1438   ,1447   ,1447   ,1447   ,1447   ,1447   ,1447   ,1488   ,1488   ,1488   ,1488   ,1488   ,1488   ,1521   ,1521   ,1521   ,1521   ,1521   ,1521)
```

If this doesnt work, could i potentially consider working with splines? Or perhaps some GAM model because i have study level data, and for each i have prev for 6 groups within each study.

```
plotdist(mydat$p_exact, histo = TRUE, demp = TRUE, breaks=40)
plotdist(mydat$p_log, histo = TRUE, demp = TRUE, breaks=40)
plotdist(mydat$p_logit, histo = TRUE, demp = TRUE, breaks=40)

fit_w  <- fitdist(mydat$prev, "weibull")
fit_g  <- fitdist(mydat$prev, "gamma")
fit_b <- fitdist(mydat$prev, "beta")
fit_ln <- fitdist(mydat$prev, "lnorm")
```

when i tried some staring values or added the option lower=c(0,0) to fitdist i got some error `the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Questions about coding ("how do I do this in R?") are off topic here. But if you can reword your question to make it about statistics rather than implementation, then it is on topic.

Comment: The fact you are exploring a set of radically different distributions and that you are not controlling for age when you do so suggests the lack of any meaningful objective to this exercise.  Could you therefore explain what you hope this will accomplish?

Comment: Actually i should adjust for age, but wasn't sure how to go about this. The main aim is to find a model that may well capture the age-specific prevalence, based on this data provided. My intuition was that a lognormal distn may be appropriate, if not explore other approaches i described in my question